# NodeJS : myFunction() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I want to make a small simple web server with an API that I could query.
So I have a server.js file that contains this:

```
var demandeController = require('./api/controller/DemandeController')
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var myRouter = express.Router();

var server = http.createServer();

myRouter.route('/demandes').get((request,response)=>{
var demandes = demandeController.getAllDemandes();
response.json(demandes);
})
app.use(myRouter);
app.listen('8080')
```

I also have my module 'DemandeController' which contains this :

```
var sql = require('../../node_modules/mssql');
///my secret config
}

module.exports = function getAllDemandes(){
   new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect().then(pool=>{
   return pool.query('SELECT * FROM DEMANDES')
   }).then(result=>{
   return JSON.stringify(result);
})
}
```

The problem is that I can not import my "DemandeController" module into my server.js file.

Here is the error message:

> TypeError: demandeController.getAllDemandes is not a function
>       at myRouter.route.get (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\server.js:11:37)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (C:_AureliaJS\HotlineFront&Back\HotlineAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Thank you for your help

Comment: You’re exporting the function itself, not an object holding the function as a method.

Comment: `require()` is essentially going to get replaced with whatever `module.exports` is, so you did `var demandeController = function getAllDemandes() {};` Not only should the latter be an anonymous function, this means that you're supposed to use `demandeController()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `getAllDemandes()` function into a variable and export the variable instead of the whole function with `module.exports`

Answer (score 0):

Either do this:

```
// ./api/controller/DemandeController
module.exports = function() { new sql... }
---
// server.js
const getAllDemandes = require('./api/controller/DemandeController')
// usage: getAllDemandes()
```

Or that:

```
// ./api/controller/DemandeController
module.exports = { getAllDemandes() { new sql... } }
---
// server.js
const DemandeController = require('./api/controller/DemandeController')
// usage: DemandeController.getAllDemandes()
```